# VS Code Hover Extension implement HoverProvider

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, hover, vscode-extensions

Trying to add [hovers](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#show-hovers) to add hovers to my VS Code extension. I was able to syntax highlighting and commands to work, but stuck on adding this hover feature.

I think my blocker is how to properly implement the [HoverProvider API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#HoverProvider). I'm doing a simple test below for a hover provider that activates when a series of tokens are recognized as the keyword `HELLO`. The hover I've implemented in my testing. I'm using `vsce package` to package and test my extension locally.

My command for the extension works, but when I hover over the word "HELLO", my hover does not appear.

[image]

**./client/extension.js**

```
const vscode = require('vscode');

function activate(context) {

    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "star-rod" is now active!');

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.mamar', () => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("The Star Rod... is powerful beyond belief. It can grant any wish. For as long as we can remember, Bowser has been making wishes like, for instance... 'I'd like to trounce Mario' or 'I want Princess Peach to like me.' Of course, Stars ignore such selfish wishes. As a result, his wishes were never granted.");
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);

    vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider('javascript', {
        provideHover(document, position, token) {

            const range = document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position);
            const word = document.getText(range);

            if (word == "HELLO") {

                return new vscode.Hover({
                    language: "Hello language",
                    value: "Hello Value"
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

function deactivate() { }

module.exports = {
    activate,
    deactivate
}
```

**./package.json**

```
    {
 "name": "star-rod-script",
 "publisher": "sonicspiral",
 "displayName": "Star Rod Script",
 "description": "Syntax highlighting for Paper Mario 64 ROM patching tool",
 "version": "1.0.1",
 "repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "https://github.com/gregdegruy/star-rod.git"
 },
 "categories": [
  "Programming Languages"
 ],
 "activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:extension.mamar",
    "onLanguage:star-rod-script"
 ],
 "engines": {
  "vscode": "^1.31.0"
 },
 "main": "./client/extension.js",
 "contributes": {
  "capabilities": {
    "hoverProvider": "true"
  },
  "commands": [
    {
     "command": "extension.mamar",
     "title": "Mamar"
    }
  ],
  "languages": [
   {
    "id": "star-rod-script",
    "extensions": [
     ".bpat",
     ".bscr",
     ".mpat",
     ".mscr"
    ],
    "aliases": [
     "Star Rod Script",
     "mscr"
    ],
    "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
   }
  ],
  "grammars": [
   {
    "language": "star-rod-script",
    "scopeName": "source.mscr",
    "path": "./syntaxes/mscr.tmLanguage.json"
   }
  ]
 },
 "devDependencies": {
  "js-yaml": "^3.12.1",
  "vscode": "^1.1.29"
 }
}
```

Comment: Does your extension get activated? Can you provide more information about what does not work and what you have tried?

Comment: Yes, but hover dialog do not appears when I hover over my test "HELLO" keyword. I just need an example how to create a hover with proper syntax, I don't fully understand the API around it.

Comment: Is it normal that you never use the token that you passed as input at `provideHover`?

Answer (score 4):

Your code allowed me to get Hovers working in my first extension. I think your mistake is having *javascript* as the `selector: vscode.DocumentSelector`. Is that there from code you copied? That should probably be set to `star-rod-script` for your extension.

I also don't have `"capabilities": {"hoverProvider": "true"}` in mine. I changed your code to:

```
disposable = vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider('star-rod-script', {  // or 'star rod script'
    //....
});

context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
```

I don't know the nuances of how you apply your extension to certain documents, but it doesn't look like you're trying to apply the hover to javascript docs. You need the selector to include the docs your extension works with. In my case that's covered by my extension name which is the language mode that shows up in the vscode status bar. More info on [document-selectors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/document-selector).

Not sure if it's needed, but I also took the return and pushed it onto the subscriptions array. Works without that, but I think that's proper??

Answer (score 3):

Your package.json looks a bit odd. I bet your extension is not activated. The "contributes/capabilites" value is something I haven't seen before. Remove that and instead change your `activationEvents` to:

```
"activationEvents": [
    "onLanguage:star-rod-script"
],
```

Comment: Updated the post with a sample screenshot, it chose that my extension is activated and I can run my test command "mamar". Not hovers appear still for the keyword HELLO even after adding this activationEvent.